# Combine Two Translucent Unpremultiplied Textures in Open GL With Blend Modes?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, alphablending, blending

I'm trying to figure out how to use Open GL to combine two unpremultiplied textures (one on top of the other).

Both textures have areas with 0-alpha.  I'd like the combined result to be unpremultiplied as well.  I've tried multiple combinations of GL_ONE, GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, etc but haven't had any luck yet.

Here's what I mean (Texture1 and Texture2 are the input textures, Combo is the desired combination):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wow...after too long on this, it looks like the image I created for this question led me to the answer.

Here's what did the trick:

glBlendFuncSeparate( GL_SRC_ALPHA,  GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );